# Real analysis ...show if its a rational number

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials

Show $(3+(2\sqrt{2})^\frac{2}{3}$ is not a rational number...

My result $x^3-6x^\frac{3}{2}+7=0$

$\{-1,1,-7,7\}$ will not equal to zero ..

Is my polynomial acceptable? 
I used contradiction for this problem and the rational zero theorem

Comment: Your title is confusing. One cannot "prove a rational number".

Comment: Do you understand the definition of rational number? What does the rational zero theorem have to do with the question?

Comment: Also, what do you mean "excepted"? Excepted from what? Please try to be more precise.

Comment: $\left(1 + \sqrt{2\,}\,\right)^{4/3}$

Comment: @AndresCaicedo:  I believe he means "accepted"

Comment: @RossMillikan Same question.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo:  He is asking whether displaying this "polynomial" (presumably showing that this number satisfies it) and the fact that it is none of the rational roots is sufficient.  I think a demonstration that it satisfies the polynomial user1352 gives plus the rational root theorem is sufficient.

Comment: @RossMillikan Sure, OK. Would you mind editing the question, so this is made clear?

Answer (score 3):

Apply the rational root theorem to $x^{6}-34x^{3}+1$.

Note that if $x=(3+2\sqrt{2})^{\frac{2}{3}}$.

$((3+2\sqrt{2})^{\frac{2}{3}})^{6}-34((3+2\sqrt{2})^{\frac{2}{3}})^{3}+1$

$=(3+2\sqrt{2})^{4}-34(3+2\sqrt{2})^{2}+1$

$=(3+2\sqrt{2})^{2}((3+2\sqrt{2})^{2}-34)+1$

$=(9+12\sqrt{2}+8)((9+12\sqrt{2}+8)-34)+1$

$=(17+12\sqrt{2})((17+12\sqrt{2})-34)+1$

$=(17+12\sqrt{2})(-17+12\sqrt{2})+1$

$=(288-289)+1$

$=-1+1=0$

Answer (score 0):

No, your "polynomial" would not be accepted because the fractional power means it is not a polynomial and the rational root theorem does not apply.  As user71352 has shown, there is another polynomial that can be used.  You need to find a polynomial with all the powers of $x$ natural numbers that the given number satisfies to use the rational root theorem.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose, reductio ad absurdum, that

$$(3+2\sqrt{2})^{\frac{2}{3}}=\frac{x}{y}\in\mathbb{Q}$$

Then,

$$(3+2\sqrt{2})^2=(\frac{x}{y})^3$$

or:

$$17+6\sqrt{2}=(\frac{x}{y})^3\in\mathbb{Q}$$

Contradiction.